# how to extract a rar file with multiple parts?

Tags: extract, rar

How should I extract a file which has more than one `rar` file that should be extracted with each other?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. Install unrar.

   ```
   sudo apt install unrar
   ```
2. Extract the first part of the group of multiple .rar files with Archive Manager, and it will automatically extract all the other parts. You can also extract the contents of an archive named FILENAME.rar from the terminal with the following command:

   ```
   unrar x FILENAME.rar # extracts all parts in the group if FILENAME.rar is the 1st part
   ```